# Oracle- Selecting max value in a column with reference to a where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table `t1`

```
site| count1 | count2
aaa | 1100   | 500 
aaa | 1000   | 400
bbb | 1500   | 700
bbb | 1200   | 600
```

I want to get the row with the highest column `value(1100)` corresponding to the site `aaa`

I am looking for a something like

```
select max(count1),count2 from t1 where site=aaa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `LAST` aggregate function

```
SELECT site
    ,MAX(count1)
    ,MAX(count2) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY count1) as count2
FROM t1
WHERE site = 'aaa'
GROUP BY site
```

OR `row_number()`

```
SELECT site
    ,count1
    ,count2
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*
        ,row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY count1 DESC
            ) as rn
    FROM t1 WHERE site = 'aaa'
    )
WHERE rn = 1;
```

OR `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` ( Oracle 12c +)

```
SELECT site
    ,count1
    ,count2 FROM t1
    WHERE site = 'aaa'
   ORDER BY count1 DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

For considering ties, you may alternatively use `dense_rank()` or `rank()` instead of `row_number()` or `WITH TIES` option in 12c

When you want to use multiple `site` ( not just `'aaa'`), you should add `PARTITION BY SITE` inside `OVER()`

OR `MAX` Analytic function

```
SELECT site
    ,count1
    ,count2
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*
        ,MAX(count1) OVER (PARTITION BY SITE) AS max_count1
    FROM t1
    WHERE site = 'aaa'
    )
WHERE count1 = max_count1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8abe1/11)

Comment: Yes.. this is exactly the query i was looking for.